# spring rabbitmq java application correct shutdown

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a standalone java application based on spring and spring-rabbit libraries. I start it like this:

```
nohup java -jar myapp.jar &
```

But sometimes I have to restart the application for upgrading it. Now I use killall -9 java, but it's not the best way. How to stop it correctly and make sure that all requests which comes to rabbit listeners of this app at that period of time will not be partially processed and will just be rejected and go to other rabbit consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - do not use `killall -9` - it sends a `SIGKILL` signal to the JVM which cannot be intercepted and will not allow for an orderly shutdown. Instead, use `killall` or `killall -15` (`15` is the default signal) that sends `SIGTERM` which is intercepted by the JVM and allows for an orderly shutdown.

Second of all - do not ACK the RabbitMQ message prematurely - only do so once the message has actually been processed. Until you ACK the message, RabbitMQ will keep it in the "unacked" state. If the consumer dies without ACKing, the message will be put back on the queue for another consumer to pick it up.

Depending on the framework you are using, you may need to register a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-) to close your application in a clean way. For example, if you are using standalone Spring, you should call [`ConfigurableApplicationContext#registerShutdownHook`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook--) on the `ApplicationContext` that you create to make sure all the beans (including RabbitMQ consumers) are closed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use autoack if you afraid of data loss. Set autoAck = false, then in your consumer, when handling a message, ack it or nack when you really finished message processing. So, you will not loss data if you somehow shutdown your java process (even if you shutdown your machine). RabbitMq will store it until your client will ack it. 
read here https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html
 in 'message acknoledgement' part.
In order to properly run your java process, write your bash script, that will stop/start/restart your programm.